# removeclass from href contains youtube facebook but all href class is removed?

Tags: jquery, href, addclass, removeclass, hashref

thanx in advance for replies

trying to addclass() for all href's with `<a>` tag

and want to exclude href contains `example1.com` , `example2.com` , `example3.com`

but i have tried a lot with

```
var exclude = ["example1.com","example2.com","example3.com"];

$('a.class').has('a[href='"+exclude+"']').removeClass('class');

or

$('a.class').has('a:contains('"+exclude+"')').removeClass('class');
```

but all class removed

hope to help me

Comment: _trying to addclass()_....i don't see this in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the array elements to create the selector for targeting elements :

```
$("a[href*='" + exclude.join("'],[href*='") + "']").removeClass('class');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ezju4hob/)**

You do not need to perform both addClass and removeClass. You can use above selector along with `.not()` to filter them out:

```
$('a').not($("[href*='" + exclude.join("'],[href*='") + "']")).addClass('class');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jsL15u11/)**

Answer (score -1):

```
 $("a.class").each(function(n){
    $(this).attr("href" , exclude[n]).removeClass('class');
 }
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: Please improve your answer, by adding more details about your solution.